# Dependency references a non-existing parent node ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length')

Tags: django, pycharm, django-migrations

I'm working on a Django project on PyCharm and it runs totally fine. I am using a venv and I had to send the project to a person. So I removed the venv folder and sent and they encountered this issue (see image).

[image]

I deleted my migrations (except `init.py`) and executed `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` and the project runs fine on my end. The dependency is automatically created (so it isn't something I created manually) and still exists after deleting and reapplying migrations but I had no issue in running the server on my end.
This is what is in my first migration file:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length'),
    ]

    operations = [
```

May I know what the issue might be for the other person?
Is it because I deleted the venv folder?
Can I just remove this dependency on my end? Will this make the server run fine on the other person's end without them having to make any changes?

Comment: Likely this is indeed because you removed the `venv` environment, since that environment had Django including the Django standard apps like `auth`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So what can I do to avoid this issue because I would need to submit without the venv folder. I had also tried running a copy of the project and deleted the venv folder and it worked on my end. Is there a way to safely remove the venv or do you recommend I start fresh with no venv to begin with?

Comment: you do not need to include the `venv` directory, but add a script to the repository that will create the virtual environment, install dependencies, and activate the `venv` to run the server.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem May I know where I can get more information to do this?

Comment: see for example https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/building-and-testing-python#starting-with-the-python-workflow-template